# Magento 1.9 - Not arrive email of Subscription Success to Newsletter

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter

I have a problem about arrive of email of subscription success of Newsletter in Magento. Email of guest is recorded in backend, but not arrive email of subscription success. Why this?
I tried to edit action of form of subscribe-home.phtml and type of block, but without success.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have enabled cronjobs ?
Did you fill in emails in System - General - Contact tab ?

Comment: Yes. Is all set, but email of subscription success not work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/66370)

Comment: Sorry for the quick response. I just wanted to say that everything is already configured cronjobs without problems. The emails are all compiled. I see now that the email of customer arrives without problems, but the email for staff not arrive. Other type of solution? Thanks.